# how to pass a entire object to another activity on Android

Tags: java, android, bundle

I'm trying to pass and recive a entire object from one activity to another, to do so, I'm using Bundle to put every atribute value separeted using a difrent "key" to each atribute of the object, but the object is too big to pass atribute to atribute. I would like to know if there is a way to pass the entire object instead of passing atribute to atribute.

Is there any how to create a constructor on the class that will recive the object? So when this class is called, it'll have to recive the object

```
Bundle valores;
            valores.putInt("CODIGO_CHECK", check.getCod());
            valores.putInt("CODIGO_MODELO", check.getCodModeloCheckList());
            valores.putInt("COD_VEICULO_W", check.getCodVeiculoW());
            valores.putString("PLACA", check.getPlacaVeiculo());
            valores.putString("DATAINICIO", check.getDataInicioVistoria());
            valores.putString("CAMINHO_FT_PLACA", check.getCaminhoArquivoFotoPlacaVeiculo());
            valores.putString("COMENTARIO", check.getComentarios());
            valores.putString("MANIFESTO", check.getNumeroManifesto());
            valores.putString("SISTEMAS", check.getIdentificadorSistemasTerceiros());
            valores.putString("CONHECIMENTO", check.getNumeroConhecimentoTransporte());
            valores.putBoolean("SOMENTERBQ", check.getFlgSomenteReboques());
            valores.putInt("STATUS_CHECK", check.getStatusCheckList());
            valores.putString("MODELO", check.getNomeCheck());
            valores.putInt("BLOCKBUTTON", 1);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SavedCheckActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(valores);
            startActivity(intent);
```

this is actualy the way I'm passing the data.. the problem is that this class(check) has much more atributes .. and to send and recive this data is getting hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly pass the object in intent as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SavedCheckActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyObject", check);
startActivity(intent);
```

Also mark the class check as Serializable as:

```
public class check implements Serializable
{
//Attribures & Methods
}
```

And you can receiver intent as:

```
Intent rcv = getIntent();
Check check = (Check) rcv.getSerializableExtra("keyObject");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Parcelable` interface to pass object from one activity to other.
The object that you want to pass its class should implement the `Parcelalbe` interface as following:

```
public class MyData implements Parcelable {
  ...
}
```

Also add the following methods inside the class

```
//write object values to parcel for storage
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags){
    //write all properties to the parcle
}

//constructor used for parcel
public MyData(Parcel parcel){
    //read and set saved values from parcel
}

//creator - used when un-parceling our parcle (creating the object)
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Property> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyData>(){

    @Override
    public MyData createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new MyData(parcel);
    }

    @Override
    public MyData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new MyData[0];
    }
};

//return hashcode of object
public int describeContents() {
    return hashCode();
}
```

Then you can pass the data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), NextActivity.class);
MyData data = new MyData();
intent.putExtra("data", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the target activity you can retrieve the object as following:

```
MyData data = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("data");
```